# SMTP server to send text messages through SSIS

Tags: smtp, sms-gateway, ssis-2012, smsmanager

I wanted to add a feature in my SSIS project, to send out a text message when ever there is any failure. Now I thought that since they have a component for email, it should be fairly
simple to add my number@tmomail.net as par below link. The method in link works fine when we use outlook and send a message in number@tmomail.net it reach my phone in form of text rather 
email.
But the problem is that, only when I try sending text using this technique using ssis, my company's SMTP server refuses to send out message because of the reciepient being untrusted.
So I wanted to seek some opinion if there are any open source SMTP server available out there which I can use for my POC to send out text message on SSIS package failure. 
I tried doing with gmail, but it didn't worked
http://www.wikihow.com/Send-a-Text-from-Email

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using the gmail smtp server (gmail.smtp.com). You can add your credential, and can start sending out email/texts.